# Alternate proof of Dini's theorem over a closed real interval

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f_n: [a, b] \to \Bbb R$ be continuous on $[a, b]$, and construct a monotone decreasing sequence of functions $(f_n)=(f_1, f_2, ...)$ converging pointwise to $f(x)=0$. Show that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly.

I've seen several different approaches to the problem posted around the internet, but wanted to play around with it a little. Would it be appropriate to consider the supremum norm here?

My initial intuition suggests that a strictly decreasing sequence of functions  $(f_n)$  would surely have $||f_n(x)||_\infty > ||f_{n+1}(x)||_\infty$. In this case, I presume one would like to show that $||f_n(x)||_\infty \to 0$ and hence the convergence is uniform, but am not exactly sure how to go about this.

**This happens to be my first ever post, so if it leaves anything to be desired, please let me know*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can be made to work. Indeed by continuity of the $f_n$, for each $n\ge 1$ there exists $x_n \in [a,b]$ such that $f_n(x_n) = ||f_n||_\infty$. It suffices to show that $||f_{n_k}||_\infty \to 0$ for some subsequence $f_{n_k}$ (since $||f_n||_\infty$ is decreasing), so by passing to a suitable subsequence of $(f_n)$ we may assume $x_n \to c$ for some $c \in [a,b]$ (compactness of $[a,b]$).

Now we consider the behaviour of these functions near $c$. Fix some $\epsilon>0$. Since $f_n \to 0$ (monotonically) pointwise, there is $N\ge 1$ so that $f_n(c) < \epsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. Furthermore, since $f_N$ is continuous we can choose $\delta>0$ such that $f_N(x) < 2\epsilon$ for $x \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap [a,b]$.

Since $x_n \to c$, for all $n$ sufficiently large we have $x_n \in (c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap [a,b]$, implying $$||f_n||_\infty = f_n(x_n) \le f_N(x_n) < 2\epsilon$$
for all $n$ sufficiently large. Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary we conclude $||f_n||_\infty \to 0$ as required.